# When should I call setContentAspectRatio?

Tags: objective-c, macos, appkit

I'd like to have an NSWindow which has a 2:1 width to height ratio while it is open, but allow it to have any ratio when full screen.

I'm initially setting the content ratio in the `AppDelegate` like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[self window] setContentAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(2, 1)];
}
```

and then setting and restoring it in the window's `NSWindowDelegate` like this:

```
- (void)windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSWindow *window = [notification object];
    [window setContentResizeIncrements:NSMakeSize(1, 1)];
}

- (void)windowDidExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSWindow *window = [notification object];
    [window setContentAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(2, 1)];    
}
```

I think this works, but I'm not sure that the `AppDelegate` is the right place to set up the window size. I've tried looking for a method on the window delegate along the lines of `windowDidLoad:`, but I can't see which one would apply. Ideally I'd only set the content ratio in one place.

Where am I supposed to put per-window initialisation code like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be cleaner to use your windowController (create a subclass if you are just using the default).  You would make that your window's delegate (and put the enter/exit code you have in that), and control the initial size of the window in windowDidLoad: